# Can I give moong dal (fried lentils) to dogs?

Tags: dogs, diet

Can I give moong dal to stray dogs? Moong dal ingredients are Moong Lentis, Edible Vegetable Oil and Edible Common Salt.

Comment: The deep fried stuff? 0_0

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Its written on the wrapper fried moong lentils.

Comment: A link to the item would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not.

Lentils on their own, properly cooked are probably fine. The fact that it's deep fried is probably *not* a good thing. And from my recollection, deep fried moong dahl's on the salty side, and too much salt is bad for dogs.

While Indian street dogs are hardy — it doesn't feel like the best idea, even if you have a big pile of 'em lying around. Junk food is as bad for them as it is for us.